# Extract key value pair from a JSON like content stored in a register in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I have multiple key-value pairs stored in an Ansible register. I want to extract each key and value from this register and pass it as parameter to another script.

**register**: fruits

The content of `fruits` looks like below:

```
{"key":"A","value":"Apple"}
{"key":"B","value":"Banana"}
{"key":"C","value":"Cherry"}
```

How to extract each *key* and *value* from `fruits` and pass it as parameter to another shell script?

```
./script.sh A Apple
./script.sh B Banana
./script.sh C Cherry
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear, is `fruits` a list of dicts?

Comment: In the other comment, you say "it's not a list". In the comment to my answer, you say (technically) "it's not a text". What is it?  Post the output of - debug: msg="{{ fruits|type_debug }}"

Answer (score 1):

If the data is a text, which is exactly what you post

```yaml
    fruits: |-
      {"key":"A","value":"Apple"}
      {"key":"B","value":"Banana"}
      {"key":"C","value":"Cherry"}
```

Then split and convert the lines. e.g.

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "./script.sh {{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
    loop: "{{ fruits.splitlines()|map('from_yaml')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: ./script.sh A Apple
  msg: ./script.sh B Banana
  msg: ./script.sh C Cherry
```

---

**Valid YAML**

The declaration

```yaml
    fruits:
      {"key":"A","value":"Apple"}
      {"key":"B","value":"Banana"}
      {"key":"C","value":"Cherry"}
```

is not a valid YAML

```yaml
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The offending line appears to be:

      {"key":"A","value":"Apple"}
      {"key":"B","value":"Banana"}
      ^ here
```

Comment: This throws an error stating, 'dict_object' has no attribute 'splitlines'. Please advise

Comment: I see. I thought the data is a text. It's not valid YAML (or JSON which is a subset of YAML). It might be a list of dictionaries if there were commas "," between the dictionaries. It's up to you to tell us what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the key value pair is defined as follows, or in some way that would be equal to the following definition:

```yaml
fruits:
  - key: A
    value: Apple
  - key: B
    value: Banana
  - key: C
    value: Cherry
```

Then the following snippet which loop through each element of fruits, and you can read both the key and value from it.

```yaml
- name: Display all cluster names
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "./script.sh {{ item.key }} {{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ fruits }}"
```

Comment: Thank you. But the content of fruits is not a list, instead it is a output of some other query  which is being stored in a register. It looks similar to 'fruits' definition in question.

Comment: More context is needed for this question please. The output of a registered variable *can* be a list of dictionaries. Otherwise your output could be a block of text, in which case Vladamir's answer. If not, give more context so we can help.